# How to infer the return type of a generic function based on its input type?

Tags: typescript, generics

I would like to make a transformation function generic, so that it returns the type based on the type of the function's arguments. How do I do that? I have tried it using conditional types, but without any success. It always returns union types, disregarding the generic type annotations.

### Goal

My goal is to make a transformation function `transformGeneric` return `TransformedA` if the input is `BaseA` and `TransformedB` if the input is `BaseB`.

### The Code

Copied from the [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-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-KJvC2d1jnyd7gjoup2mEuMpKUpcNKBYyvuvHElxpfZGOba1xPp6BhOjad7rD4th8T5t8-HZN7qgA).

The types of the base data structure:

```js
// Bases types
interface BaseA {
  type: "A";
  text: "A";
}

interface BaseB {
  type: "B";
  text: "B";
}

type Bases = ({ type: "A" } & BaseA) | ({ type: "B" } & BaseB)
```

Variables that are of those types:

```js
const baseASample: BaseA = {
  type: "A",
  text: "A",
}

const baseBSample: BaseB = {
  type: "B",
  text: "B",
}
```

The types of the transformed data structure:

```js
interface Transformed {
  transformedType: string;
  text: string;
}

interface TransformedA extends Transformed {
  transformedType: "a";
  text: "Something else for A";
}

interface TransformedB extends Transformed {
  transformedType: "b";
  text: "Something else for B";
}
```

The transformation functions:

```js
const transformA = (baseA: BaseA): TransformedA => ({
  transformedType: "a",
  text: "Something else for A",
})

const transformB = (baseB: BaseB): TransformedB => ({
  transformedType: "b",
  text: "Something else for B",
})
```

The basic generic transformation function I want to improve:

```js
// Generic transformation function that just returns the parent type Transformed
const transformGeneric = <B extends Bases>(base: Bases): null | Transformed => {
  switch (base.type) {
    case "A": {
      const ret = transformA(base)
      return ret
    }

    case "B": {
      const ret = transformB(base)
      return ret
    }

    default:
      return null
  }
}

// returns the parent type "Transformed"
const transformedA = transformGeneric(baseASample)
const transformedB = transformGeneric(baseBSample)
```

Two generic transformation functions that are using conditional types:

```js
// Generic transformation function that is unable to resolve the types
const transformGeneric2 = <B extends Bases>(base: Bases): B extends BaseA ? TransformedA : (B extends BaseB ? TransformedB : null) => {
  switch (base.type) {
    case "A": {
      const ret = transformA(base)
      return ret
    }

    case "B": {
      const ret = transformB(base)
      return ret
    }

    default:
      return null
  }
}

// returns a union :(
const transformedA2 = transformGeneric2(baseASample)
const transformedB2 = transformGeneric2(baseBSample)
```

or

```js
// Generic transformation function that can only resolve a single case
const transformGeneric3 = <B extends Bases>(base: Bases): B extends BaseA ? TransformedA : Transformed | null => {
  switch (base.type) {
    case "A": {
      const ret = transformA(base)
      return ret
    }

    case "B": {
      const ret = transformB(base)
      return ret
    }

    default:
      return null
  }
}

const transformedA3 = transformGeneric3(baseASample)
const transformedB3 = transformGeneric3(baseBSample)
```

Unfortunately, both don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a simple map type, which maps from `type` to the `Transformed` type.

```
type TransformMap = {
  A: TransformedA
  B: TransformedB
}
```

In the generic function, we use the `type` property of `B` to determine the return type.

```
const transformGeneric = <B extends Bases>(base: B): TransformMap[B["type"]] => {
  /* ... */
}
```

The implementation of the function would be a bit messy with a `switch` statement. TypeScript does not do control flow analysis properly to understand the statement and would complain about the return types.

I would tidy it up to also use a map.

```
const transformGeneric = <B extends Bases>(base: B): TransformMap[B["type"]] => {

  const map: Record<keyof TransformMap, (args: any) => any> = {
    A: transformA,
    B: transformB
  }

  return map[base.type](base)
}
```

Now we get the correct return types.

```
const transformedA = transformGeneric(baseASample) // TransformedA
const transformedB = transformGeneric(baseBSample) // TransformedB
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFNQdwQwHYBdRIPagMYCdJydHKtogM4Bma2AtvgJZoKjkCuCmSDTSAFvsWUo1SoIgBN8RUkmwsOLXKAAUAITilIpAJSgARushjQjUHSQiAREgCeAB0gXmdSABsj6UaASQYoabPlFJQAVEgQKKmpDLQA6AFgAKESQUDUNERt7UkS6ZEhscjhMaDTIAEFQAG9E0FQ7SAAuUAsyiwBuGtRIAA8kJpb2xIBfRJy8gqKSgxUqzszG5pVBhNqCXv6ljoSRpIT51IMRAF5lSrr7ftbQIdAAMgONMp0AH1PzhYsl67uHyBUtUYJTCMaR6AxlADKcGothcC1KFRO1RW70uFgANHMen1mq1MdtAcDwih9BoVFCYXCmqUZki5vUNhisetFkyCbsUqFBJFDO9sglcgQJsVQFzwkIokZkaswhEaIZggy-DJcgBzLarbFNfxqrY7MZCwoisVyyUVbGQBBiEQmiW86UCcU8sSKi7NODLTUsiwQtBRXhq0CuDTMKigVp6wGC-JG6C250zC1Wm2yu1Suap52uj66T1db2+-08QPB6BCVLLfUJTmZmj0EysdicEGJImgmTcmiI5Sk8rU8FaJrx+ViREAPlOGc7kuz-Q9+K9OJ9fsgAYQqqDLhD5bxwwBuzbKA7TpotJ7037ZMHotrktpE6UDuPpoVSosuYX+aXhdXxfXm+3MMlnxIZ90BfZh2oABZOBbFAOkUTKIdb0MMpOhUZDp0MFRhkBFIAHFLXyOhMEdU16yYRsOC4VA+BQAArFhQVwJAFHCWjoFsOBcGQd4bywsRWxBI9b0I7xsBI+DQAAHkTXpLWtX5SDHJRe2pa9IJg2wAG0VG0qx6gsABdIz4InZFOkPUBaFsJoACVIGBbAxGkgBrSBrDQch+JPaDYPRZRuNVUgmkQawdCOCcwonBDalqJCyIlMpP1qDDEsiHCUSrWoWLY6zYO03sYnmIzVIMfcqxSXLsHY3hOO4y0j3qZpIMMCwhOJdKR27Z8JTE4jMDKx4KVhSAdBrAS0KBYSurvKTesifqJMG3tyWhUbxrAVqxEyoA)

Comment: Sounds promising! Creating a type map seems like a good idea. I'll try this :)

Comment: Is there a way without `any`?

Comment: @michaelschufi - You could replace `(args: any) => any` with `Function` but it does not really make a difference.